# Trouble rendering view associated with nested route in ember

Tags: ember.js

I am having trouble with ember.js. Using the following routing setup I can not get the entries/new route to work. The index works fine but the entries/new template just refuses to render. I think it is where I am trying to render the view inside renderTemplate but I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrect. Your help would be much appreciated.

```
Journal.Router.map ->
    @resource 'entries', {path: '/' }, ->
        @route 'new'
        return
    return

Journal.EntriesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    renderTempalte: ->
        @render 'entriesNew', {
            into: 'application'
        }
    setupController: (controller) ->
        controller.set 'heading', 'new entry'
        return

Journal.EntriesNewView = Ember.View.extend
    className: ['entries-new']
    templateName: 'entries/new'

Journal.EntriesNewController = Ember.Controller.extend
    heading: "New Journal Entry"

    createEntry: ->
        title = @get 'newTitle'
        content = @get 'newContent'

        if !title.trim()  and !content.trim() then return null

        Journal.Entry.createRecord
            title: title
            content: content

        @get('store').commit()
        return
```

And the entries/new template

```
{{ heading }}

{{view Ember.TextField id="entry-title" placeholder="Enter a title" valueBinding="newTitle"}}

{{view Ember.TextArea id="entry-content" placeholder="What do you have to say?" valueBinding="newContent"}}

<button {{action "createEntry"}} class="save">Save</button>
```

Comment: I am having about the same problem. I fail to understand how templates are rendered and where they are rendered in case of nested routes.

Comment: If you are having a hard time with this I highly recommend [Peepcode's Fire Up Ember.js Tutorial](https://peepcode.com/products/emberjs). It answered a lot of questions and cleared a lot of confusion about when and why you should nest routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your route, the 'into' should target the route that has your {{outlet}}

```
renderTempalate: ->
    @render 'entriesNew', {
        into: 'entries'
    }
```

Though the renderTemplate hook's default action is to render into it's resources outlet, so as long as your Entries template has an {{outlet}} in it and your obeying the strict naming conventions, you don't need to define that hook at all.

If that's not the issue maybe post your Entries template

Comment: Thank you, I ended up scrapping what I was working on after watching the Peepcode tutorial and realized that I was using nested routes completely wrong.